# How to get details on all the models used for evaluating ACA?

Tags: macroeconomics, fiscal-policy

I am trying to track down the models and the underpinnings/details for them for models that may have been used to evaluate the ACA/Obamacare.  I am aware of Gruber's (proprietary) model, and am thinking that the Urban Institute's HIPSM model may have been used, but not sure if there are others.  Even for those two, it seems I'll need to do a good bit of research to figure out what's in them and how they work.

Comment: models used by whom to evaluate it? If your looking for CBO, check [their site](www.cbo.gov)

Answer (score 2):

In terms of actually getting it passed as legislation, the only evaluation that has any real significance is the one done by the CBO, as that's the official scorecard for Congress and debates that come up on the floor. I have no idea what the specific models they use are called, but I do know they are very linear and simplistic (by design) compared to other mainstream models. It's definitely bound to be a fruitful search if you look there.